# insert if not exist without making column unique

Tags: mysql

I am searching for the answer of this question by many days. There are some answers on stackoverflow and on ther sites which I really don't understand. Basically I need to insert only if cell value for particular column does not exist.

Ex: See below table, if their are some duplicate names present it's ok like 'sandy' and 'edward'. But for some names like 'wilson' I don't want to insert. I don't want to make name column unique at all.

[image]

**Note :** Please don't give any complicated answer or procedural queries, it should be easy to remember.

Comment: you should make another column/table to determine which name can't duplicate

Comment: What is your criteria for name to be unique?

Comment: How do you decide which name can be duplicate and which shouldn't be?

Answer (score 0):

you should make another column/table to determine which name can't duplicate

Then, you **select** the name whether can be duplicate or not from that table and then insert based on result

Comment: Don't want to create another column or table. It should be query.

Comment: Can you give me a query where nothing duplicate in name is allowed? From there I can build something.

Comment: @WeAreRight - You've said you want to prevent some duplicates but not others, so you'll need to define which should not duplicate (or you could define which values allow duplicates). AKZhang is suggesting using a table for this, but it could be a table, an array, or a even string you define inline.

Comment: it is an on demand system decision, I just need to pass name as a string! it is ok if it comes in query as string something like : insert into table (id , name) values (some_id,'some_name') if not exists name='some_name';

Comment: I made complex scenario simple here. For which value we don't want to insert is not know from start , it will be known before query execution and it may change dynamically such is the scenario. That's why I said no to saving names in table or column.

Comment: @WeAreRight from where the query or system can know that this *name* can't be duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `checkbox` at HTML FORM.

You fill form values

If that checkbox `checked`, then before inserting in database, it will will check if exists then no insertion. If not exists then insert.

If that checkbox is not checked, then insert blindly

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
INSERT INTO info (id, name)
SELECT null, 'wilson' FROM any_other_table_name 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT name FROM info WHERE name = 'wilson'
) ;
```

It will not insert if multiple entry.

Comment: Can you explain " SELECT null, 'wilson' FROM any_other_table_name " why to use this . Also where is statement which will provide new values to insert?

Comment: OK, usually `insert into` is followed by `values(.....)` but then we can't write the where clause there So `select` is being used. 
insert into will insert new values based on the where if not found the name you provide.

Comment: what if i need to insert the values like id=10, name='ron'.  How query will be with above constraints?

Comment: Not Working : insert into info values (id,name)  select 10,'ron' from info where not exists ( select name from info where name='wilson' );

Comment: You know `values()` should not be used.it would be like:

`insert into info (id,name) select 10,'ron' from info where not exists ( select name from info where name='wilson' )`